# CORS not working with API Gateway (HTTP) and SQS Proxy Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have the following setup:

1. API Gateway with HTTP Protocol
2. It has integration to SQS (SendMessage action)
3. CORS is enabled on API

I am facing following error when I call the endpoint from browser:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

> For a Lambda proxy integration or HTTP proxy integration, you can still set up the required OPTIONS response headers in API Gateway. However, your backend is responsible for returning the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers, because a proxy integration doesn't return an integration response.

Is it not clear how SQS can return headers, because the integration is between API Gateway -> SQS

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you have linked to describes using CORS with REST API Gateways. If you are using HTTP API Gateways then the relevant documentation is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html.

When using REST API Gateway to implement a service proxy to another AWS service like S3 / SQS / SNS you can set any headers you want on the method response - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-response-parameters.

If you're using OpenAPI specifications to define your REST APIs then these headers can be specified using (for example):

```
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: "aws"
        responses:
          "200":
            statusCode: "200"
            responseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'OPTIONS,GET'"
```

If you're defining the REST API in the AWS Console then these values can be set in the Integration Response panel. Note the embedded single quotes are important here i.e. `"'*'"` to signify that you want the header to be the literal value `*` (or whatever you specify).

Comment: I have tried something similar, but I was getting this error: `Operations on header access-control-allow-origin a
re restricted`